# Reverting pvcreate on a Windows System Recovery partition

Tags: linux, windows, lvm, data-recovery

As the title says I incorrectly ran:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb1
```

Where sdb1 was a Windows System Reserved partition. Now I know I could probably use the Windows CD to recreate it, but is there a way to do it from within GNU/Linux?

I can mount the partition from Linux and also see the boot sector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - Just copy over the Boot/ directory and bootmgr file on to your root partition and install/modify GRUB to boot into the root partition. This is a bit of a quick fix as I wasn't able to revert the operation.

Read more [here](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=409)

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't got a backup, the answer is no.

Comment: If it means anything, testdisk can see all the files.

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me - I issued `pvcreate` on a 200GB music partition :)
Successfully recovered it using `testdisk`:
Go to `[Advanced] Filesystem Utils`, select the damaged partiton. You may need to specify its `[Type]` explicitly.
Go to `[Boot]` and `[Rebuild BS]`, and after it succeeds, `[Repair MFT]`.

Hope this helps someone.